# Can't animate properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

I've made a simple text changer but I can't figure out how to use animate.css properly. It works but I want the animations to be delayed and not as fast as  now. I tried using `.delay` but it's not working. I'm pretty new with jQuery and animations.

```
<div class="col-7 justify-content-center">
        <span id="role"></div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var roles = ['role 1', 'role 2', 'role 3'];
        //used to determine which is the next roles to be displayed
        var counter = 0;
        var $role = $('#role')
        //repeat the passed function at the specified interval - it is in milliseconds
        setInterval(function () {


            //display the role and increment the counter to point to next role
            $role.text(roles[counter++]);
            //if it is the last role in the array point back to the first item
            if (counter >= roles.length) {
                counter = 0;
            }

            $role.fadeIn('slow');
            $role.fadeOut('slow');
        }, 4000 )
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert `delay(whatever_number).` before the `.fadeOut()`, if that's what you mean. Also, your span tag should be closed properly (maybe that was just a typo in the question - `</div>` instead of `</span>`)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var roles = ['role 1', 'role 2', 'role 3'];
  //used to determine which is the next roles to be displayed
  var counter = 0;
  var $role = $('#role')
  //repeat the passed function at the specified interval - it is in milliseconds
  setInterval(function() {


    //display the role and increment the counter to point to next role
    $role.text(roles[counter++]);
    //if it is the last role in the array point back to the first item
    if (counter >= roles.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    $role.fadeIn('slow');
    $role.delay(2500).fadeOut('slow');
  }, 4000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-7 justify-content-center">
  <span id="role"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm really dumb i tried with putting delay on both fadeIn and fadeOut. Stupid mistake. Thanks for the help man !

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted or/and give it an upvote